# Place bootstrap column inside row side by side php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place two bootstrap column inside each row dynamically using php. Inside row at left side I'm trying to print odd number array and at right side trying to place even number array, but bootstrap columns not getting aligned side by side

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xl-12">
<div class="card-body">
<?php 
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
foreach($arr as $data) {
?>
<div class="form-group row">
<?php if($data%2 == 1) { ?>
<label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold"><?php echo $data; ?></label>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<textarea class="form-control" name="<?php echo $data; ?>"></textarea>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold"><?php echo $data; ?></label>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<textarea class="form-control" name="<?php echo $data; ?>"></textarea>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

May You need something like this ?

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
echo "<table style='margin-left: 15px;'><tr>";
$count = 1; 
foreach($arr as $res){

echo'
<td>
<label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">'.$res.'</label>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<textarea class="form-control" name="'.$res.'"></textarea>
</div>
</td>';

    if ($count++ % 2 == 0) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    } 
}
echo"</tr></table>";
```

EDIT: THIS IS YOUR FULL CODE

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-12">
                <div class="card-body">
                <?php
                $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
                echo "<table style='margin-left: 15px;'><tr>";
                $count = 1; 
                foreach($arr as $data){

                echo'
                <td>
                <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">'.$data.'</label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="'.$data.'"></textarea>
                </div>
                </td>';

                if ($count++ % 2 == 0) 
                {
                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                } 
                }
                echo"</tr></table>"; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make it with my code? Your is in <tr><td>

Comment: I think it's your code, you just need to replace it with the one I made!